# Sublime text 2 Plugin Development - How do I get the language of the current file

Tags: localization, sublimetext2

**== UPDATE ===**

So I realized that Sublime already has a command for adding comments. So if I have code inserted like this:

```
comment = " ----------------------------------------" + '\n'
comment += " " + title + '\n'
comment += " @author " + author + '\n'
comment += " @url " + url + '\n'
comment += " ---------------------------------------" + '\n'
comment = self.view.run_command('toggle_comment')
code = items['code']
layout = comment + code
self.view.replace(edit, sel[0], layout)
```

How do I get the command to work so that it comments out the comment variable? Thanks.

***Initial Question***

I am creating a plugin for Sublime Text 2 and want to make sure that when it inserts/replaces code it inserts comments as well, but to do this I need for it to insert the correct comment types for the various languages. I know that I can run the following command:

`view.settings().get('syntax')`

And that will return something like this:

`Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage`

Is there a way to have it return just PHP, Python, C++, etc.

I'm sure I could do a substring command in Python, but since I can see an easy way of seeing all file settings I wanted to make sure there wasn't a quick easy way of doing this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for scope_name ?

> **scope_name(point)** | ***String*** | Returns the syntax name assigned to the character at the given point.

Comment: I would still have to do a substring method on that as it returns `source.python keyword.control.import.python` - I'm hoping there is a way that I'm missing that will just return Python or PHP for example.